# PDF form with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf-generation, itext, pdf-form

How can i create a fillable PDF file in iTextSharp. As of right now I can create a pdf file with text in it, however I'm struggling in creating fillable fields. Any help or sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It's more easy to make pdf form from third party softwares like ***Adobe LiveCycle Designer*** than coding with iTextsharp. You just have to put some textbox, checkbox or radio buttons as required with your form, setting its fonts, font size & its datatype.

Mark down all the field names(like "TextField1" etc). Create a new webform that contains some textboxes which feeds data to that fields.

You can then fill up that form easily with the code like below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var reader = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("~/Emptyform.pdf"));
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
        stamper.AcroFields.SetField("TextField1", TextBox1.text);
        stamper.FormFlattening = true;
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();
        File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath("~/Filledform.pdf"),output.ToArray());        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
AcroFields fields = pdf.AcroFields;
fields.SetField("field_1", "1");
fields.SetField("field_2", "2");
```